# Lost in Reduction of order

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$(x-1)y''-xy'+y=0$, $y_1(x)=e^x$, Find a second linearly independent solution of the ODE using reduction of order.

I have spent hours trying to figure out this problem. I went to Tutorvista... but they gave me a solution that is not correct.

$y_2(x)=u(x)e^x$

$y_2'(x)=u'e^x+ue^x$

$y_2''(x)=u''e^x+u'e^x++u'e^x+ue^x$

Then you plug them back into the original equation, but my answer keeps going way off. I'm not even going to write all of this arithmetic down..

Comment: @Amzoti. You are too fast for me ! Take my age into consideration !! Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici: Please be my guest if you have done the solution - I enjoy reading your posts and it is not about the fastest, but the best. :-)

Comment: @Amzoti. This coming from you, be sure I really appreciate !

Comment: @Azmoti I think so? Did you just do that yourself? That fast?

Comment: I don't get how to solve from there, actually.

Comment: i knew that part.. but my integration seems funky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using what you have posted, we have:

$$\tag 1 e^x ((x-1) u''(x)+(x-2) u'(x)) = 0$$

Next, we let $w = u' \implies w' = u''$ and substitute into $(1)$, yielding:

$$e^x((x-1) w' + (x-2) w)) = 0$$

This can be solved using Separation of Variables as:

$$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{1}{w}~dw = \int \dfrac {2-x}{x-1}~dx$$

This yields:

$$\ln w = \ln(x-1)-x+c \implies w = c(x-1)e^{-x}$$

Next, we have:

$$u'(x) = w(x) = c(x-1)e^{-x}$$

Integrating yields:

$$u(x) = a x e^{-x} + b$$

From the original, we have:

$$y_2(x) = u e^x = ax + b e^x$$

You can see more examples of these at: [*Reduction of Order*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/ReductionofOrder.aspx).

Comment: @Azmoti, I see where I went wrong! Thanks!

Comment: You are welcome - I would just practice more examples from that site to get faster and more accurate.